# docker PXE server failed, cannot initialize iptables; needs root, even though already root

Tags: iptables, docker, root, pxe

I'm trying to setup a PXE boot server on the control node of a multi node mini cluster, then having each node connect to a docker swarm.
Following the instructions on this site (https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/12/07/pxe-netboot-docker/), i'm running the command `docker run jpetazzo/pxe` as root, but the docker container is telling me that i'm not using root, even though I am.

```
root@debian:/home/anthony# docker run jpetazzo/pxe
Setting up iptables...
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

How should I resolve this issue? Is there a better/easier way of setting up a PXE boot server?

Edit: I'm using the latest version of Debian and Docker

Answer (score 0):

From the [README.md](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pxe/blob/master/README.md) file, you should run this as

- Run the container with PXECID=$(docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN -d pxe)
- Give it an extra network interface with ./pipework br0 $PXECID 192.168.242.1/24
- Put the network interface connected to your machines on the same bridge with e.g. brctl addif br0 eth0 (don't forget to move eth0 IP address to br0 if there is one).

i.e. your docker container needs NET_ADMIN on the host.